# I'm attempting to display an image determined by the radio button that is chosen

Tags: javascript

The point of this specific project is to calculate and display the value of the selected coin and quantity and display the appropriate number of copies of the image of the selected coin...

This is what I have so far...

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Coin Calc</title>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .error {
            color: red;
            font-size: 2em;
        }

            .error span {
                display: block;
            }

        .answer {
            color: black;
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function ProcessForm() {
            if (DoValidation()) {
                DoCalculation();
            }
        }
        function DoValidation() {
            document.getElementById("results2").innerHTML = "";
            bValid = true;
            error = "";
            if (document.getElementById("ddQuantity").value == "0") {
                bValid = false;
                error = "<span>Must select a quantity</span>";
                document.getElementById("results").className = "error";
            }
            else {
                if (isNaN(document.getElementById("ddQuantity").value)) {
                    bValid = false;
                    error = "<span>Must enter a number</span>";
                    document.getElementById("results").className = "error";
                }

            }

            if ((document.getElementById("rbQuarters").checked == false) &&
                (document.getElementById("rbDimes").checked == false) &&
             (document.getElementById("rbNickels").checked == false) &&
                 (document.getElementById("rbPennies").checked == false)) {
                bValid = false;
                error = error + "<span>Must pick coin</span>";
                document.getElementById("results").className = "error";



            }

            if ((document.getElementById("rbQuarters").checked == true) &&
             (document.getElementById("rbDimes").checked == true) &&
          (document.getElementById("rbNickels").checked == true) &&
              (document.getElementById("rbPennies").checked == true)) {
                bValid = false;
                error = error + "<span>Must pick one coin: REFERSH!</span>";
                document.getElementById("results").className = "error";



            }
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = error;
            return bValid;

        }
        function DoCalculation() {
            //get fahrenheit value from text box
            t = document.getElementById("ddQuantity").value;

            //calculate results
            if (document.getElementById("rbQuarters").checked) {
                answer = .25 * t
                label = "Total Amount";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("rbDimes").checked) {
                answer = .10 * t
                label = "Total Amount";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("rbNickels").checked) {
                answer = .05 * t
                label = "Total Amount";
            }
            if (document.getElementById("rbPennies").checked) {
                answer = .01 * t
                label = "Total Amount";
            }




            //display result
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<strong>" + answer + " </strong>" + label;
            document.getElementById("results").className = "answer";


            resultString = "";
 resultString3 ="";


            for (var i = 0; i <= ddQuantity; i++) {
                if (document.getElementById("rbQuarters").checked) {
                    resultString == resultString + "\images\dime.gif";


                }
                if (document.getElementById("rbDimes").checked) {
                    resultString == resultString + "~\Images\dime.gif";

                }
                if (document.getElementById("rbNickels").checked) {
                    resultString == resultString + "~\Images\nickel.gif";

                }
                if (document.getElementById("rbPennies").checked) {
                    resultString == resultString + "~\Images\penny.gif";

                }
            }

            document.getElementById("results2").innerHTML = resultString;
 document.getElementById("results3").innerHTML = resultString3;



        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="#" method="get">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="ddQuantity">
                    Quantity
                </label>
                <select name="ddQuantity"
                        id="ddQuantity">
                    <option value="">Please select coin quantity</option>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>

            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="rbQuarters">
                    Quarter
                </label>
                <input type="radio"
                       name="rbQuarters"
                       id="rbQuarters"
                       value=".25" />
                <label for="rbDimes">
                    Dimes
                </label>
                <input type="radio"
                       name="rbDimes"
                       id="rbDimes"
                       value=".10" />
                <label for="rbNickels">
                    Nickels
                </label>
                <input type="radio"
                       name="rbNickels"
                       id="rbNickels"
                       value=".05" />
                <label for="rbPennies">
                    Pennies
                </label>
                <input type="radio"
                       name="rbPennies"
                       id="rbPennies"
                       value=".01" />



            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="button"
                       value="calculate"
                       name="btnSumbit"
                       onclick="ProcessForm();" />
            </li>
            <li id="results">


            </li>
            <li id="results2">


            </li>
 </ul>

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Why can't I unselect a coin?

Comment: that's because the radio buttons each have a different name and are not treated as one group

Comment: @Jsm I can see that, but I was asking the OP why.

Comment: I apologize. I must have omitted my question. The images are suppose to display - which they are not and also be repeated depending on what the user has chosen on the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things.

- Did you really mean to use a radio button?  You only want a radio button if ONE of the options can be selected.  In which case you need to group them by giving them the same name.
- You're incorrectly trying to assign resultString with the comparison operator `==`.  One `=` is for setting a variable two or three are for comparing (depending on how "strict" the comparison should be). The fact that you aren't chaining your if statements and keep adding to the resultString leads me to believe you meant to use checkboxes instead of radios.

  ```
  if (document.getElementById("rbQuarters").checked) {
    // Dime image for quarters?
    resultString == resultString + "\images\dime.gif";
  }
  if (document.getElementById("rbDimes").checked) {
    resultString == resultString + "~\Images\dime.gif";
  }
  ```
- Why does every subsequent path contain `~`?  Also, you can't just append a path to innerHTML and expect an image.  A string is just text.  You'll need to build the element and append it to the document.

  ```
  var imgs = document.createElement("span");
  var img1 = document.createElement("img");
      img1.src = "path_to/img.jpg";
      imgs.appendChild(img1);
  var img2 = document.createElement("img");
      img2.src = "path_to/img.jpg";
      imgs.appendChild(img2);

  document.getElementById("someID").appendChild(imgs);
  ```